# Fetching data into textbox

Tags: forms, echo

I am trying to finish my school project.

This is what my site looks like:

[image]

I am fetching daha via the "Getir" button using AJAX. This is working very well but I want to make the second row editable.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['uyeid']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ad']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['soyad']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['eposta']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['uyestatusu']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$duzenlenemez</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ad']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['soyad']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['eposta']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['uyestatusu']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

I am ready to supply extra code if anyone needs it to figure out more.

Comment: I don't really get your question, is this snippet the script where the AJAX request catches its data? Also: what do you mean by editable, are you working with a database that you want to updade or do you just want the row to consist of input fields? A litle more information would probably help.

Comment: sorry for late answer, I just wanted to write data to input and good thing I solved this. I have realy bad English so I think I couldn't write my problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested and found this subject one google I am writing this:
As I said I wanted to make second row editable so I needed to wrote data to inputs. Like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['uyeid']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['ad']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['soyad']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['eposta']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['uyestatusu']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$duzenlenemez</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['ad']."'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['soyad']."'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['eposta']."'/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['uyestatusu']."'/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Output picture: http://puu.sh/8uSDl.png